# Django Rest Framework - prevent access to API?

Tags: django, api, rest, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework and Token Authentication. Everything works great so far.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication#tokenauthentication

But I'm realizing that anyone could create a third party app that hooks into my API. There'd be no way for me to detect it or stop it.

Am I missing something? I followed the directions, and I:

- Send "username=blah&password=blah" to https://example.com/api/auth/, and receive a Token in return. Anyone could do this from a third party app.
- That token is passed in the authentication header to retrieve data from the API. Anyone could do this if they have their user token.

Even if a user knows their own Token, I only want them to be able to access the API through the official native app.

**1. How do I secure my API (using Token authentication) and make sure that only MY apps can connect to it?**

**2. Could I include some kind of secret key in a header? I'm using HTTPS in production, are headers as well as form data (username/password) interceptable/readable? (By the person running the app).**

Still learning, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I don't understand you question fully, but:

yes, everyone *with a username and a password* in your application can create tokens, *if you added `obtain_auth_token` to your urlconfig* (what you don't have to).

So you can:

- only give *your* apps username and password
- or deactivate the `obtain_auth_token` view and create the tokens in the admin or manually.

To answer your HTTPS question: 
HTTPS encryption is between the client and the server and lies *between* TCP and HTTP. So everyone in between (a man in the middle) can't see any headers, data, or even the path. When using [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) the hostname (`Host` header) is visible, but nothing else.

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: you need `obtain_auth_token` when your API users should be able to generate their own tokens. Of course they need to authenticate with username and password to get the token. 

If you just create a valid token for each user (for example with signals, or your custom user model, or .. ) you don't need `obtain_auth_token`, you only have to provide a way for the users to get their own token.

Comment: The Django Admin or directly by Using the model